# Autoscroll if initial document is smaller than the size of the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery and javascript to dynamically load data from my server when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var bodyHeight = $(document).height() - windowHeight;
    var scrollPercentage = (scrollTop / bodyHeight);

    if(scrollPercentage == 1) {
        // Load content
        }
    }
});
```

The only problem is that if the height of the viewport is large enough, then the initial document height would be smaller than the height of the viewport. Then, the user would not be able to scroll and my code would not work. What is the best way to deal with this? I thought about repeatedly checking in the javascript if the heigh of the document exceeds the height of the viewport, and continuing to load in content until it does exceed the height of the viewport:

```
while ($(document).height() == $(window).height()) {
    if (working == false) {
        working = true;
        getData();
    }
}
```

This `working` variable is a variable I set to true whenever I fetch data. Then, within the ajax callback I have a timeout that change working to false in 1 second. the getData function fetches the data from my server. However, the page seems to just get stuck on this while loop. (It doesn't load)

Comment: For your user's sake, I hope you don't have a footer _below_ that content that they need to be able to get to in order to click "contact" or something, and don't want people to be able to link to your page because the initial view doesn't include the things they saw after scrolling. There are a lot of good reasons why automatic infinite scroll is not super great UX. (make users decide whether to see more content, through a button or something, and update the URL when they do so they can refer others to the same thing they're seeing, is far better UX)

Comment: I think auto scroll is a better fit for my application since pagination is most often used with ecommerce sites. Plus, I can always use a sticky footer if I decide to add a footer. I am still laying out the bare bones of my application so I don't know yet.

Comment: note that there's a difference between pagination and "show more results" that loads more data on the same page, but adds a little marker to the URL so that your application knows how which data was showing.